# How did we get that derivative of a function is equal to limit?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Assume that $y = f(x)$. Then, we have, by the definition of derivative:

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{ f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

I don't understand the motivation to divide by $h$. I thought that the value of function at a small value of $h$ greater than $x$ minus the the value of function at $x$ will give the small change in the value of the function. But why does it get divided by $h$?

Forgive my inability to express the formula in the scientific form as I don't know how to.

Comment: That is some creative notation.  [Please read this, then edit your post appropriately.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Indeed, go  [Please read this, and edit your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  In particular, in addition to enclosing your equation in dollar sides, replace  with `\to` and surround it all with a dollar sign on each end.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative effectively reflects how much a curve is moving vertically **relative to** a very small change horizontally. In this sense, it it a generalisation of the slope between two points. This is why a ratio is used, since we need some way of taking both horizontal, $\Delta x$, and vertical change, $\Delta y$, and then comparing them. Consider the triangle constructed between two points on the curve in the figure below. The slope is the ratio of the change in $x$ and $y$. When we move $x_1$ rightwards very close to $x_2$, the triangle's slope should represent the slope at the point $x_1=x_2$ alone. Both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ get smaller (and eventually $0$) when the points are moved together but the relationship between $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ is what is important.

However, if we ignore the horizontal change, we are left with just the vertical change, $\Delta y$. Without the context of the small horizontal change, this value is fairly meaningless and for most sensible functions, it will just be $0$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture. When you divide the small change in the function value by $h$ you are finding the slope of the line joining two nearby points on the graph. The derivative is the limit of that slope when the points are very close together.

Answer (score 1):

If we **don't** divide by $\,h\,$ then the limit is $0$ if and only if the
function is continuous at $\,x.\,$ Not all functions are continuous, so it
is important to check. If we **do** divide by $\,h\,$ then the limit, if it
exists, is the the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the function at the
point $\,(x,f(x)).\,$ This is often important for applications.